# in AWS redirect both domain.com and www.domain.com to another domain

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an old website domain that I need to redirect both the www.domain.com and domain.com to www.newdomain.com in AWS. I set up a bucket for domain.com, set an A record up in Route 53 with an alias that points to the bucket and that works fine, it redirects to www.newdomain.com as intented. Now I want to make it so www.domain.com redirects to www.newdomain.com as well. First I tried to create a bucket with that name, set the redirect to newdomain.com and that didnt seem to work. Then I tried creating a cname record within Route 53 for domain.com FOR www.domain.com but that did not work either.

How can I get both domain.com AND www.domain.com to redirect to www.newdomain.com with AWS?

Comment: We need for you to be more specific when you say something "didn't work."

Comment: when you go to domain.com it redirects to www.newdomain.com. When you go to www.domain.com it goes to 500 internal error. One thing to note is the domain at one point was set up with a website in AWS but since new sites were built at this point we just want to redirect the domain to a new site we are branding for the same space.

Comment: Taking a look at the response headers should give you some information that might help explain what's going on with the 500 errors.  If you don't have a way of doing that, a browser extension, like [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http-headers/nioieekamcpjfleokdcdifpmclkohddp?hl=en) can be useful. The `curl` command line tool is also useful.

Comment: I wonder if I just need to start from scratch on this? I am new to AWS, if I was to start over, delete everything, with the nameservers from the domain being pointed to AWS already, how would I redirect both www.domain.com and domain.com to www.newdomain.com?